# Problem with scraping data from the web. How to use XPath in Google Sheets correctly?

Tags: xpath, web-scraping, google-sheets, xml-parsing

I am trying to create monitoring table where tracking number of the parcel from one cell concatenates with the tracking website URL and imports current status.

On another site I use such construction and it works:

```
=IMPORTXML(CONCATENATE("https://site.url/tracking/?cargo_number=",A2), "//div[@class='status']")
```

But it is not working on this site: https://t.17track.net/en#nums=RP033693154CN

I tried to use the whole XPath by copying it from Google developer Tools:

```
/html/body/main/div/article/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/dl[1]/dd[1]/div/p
```

Also I tried to use the and of the Xpath tail like in the first example but it response #N/A anyway.

I need to get such a response in one cell:

```
2018-10-13 17:05
```

and in another:

```
UKRAINE, KYIV 232, Attempted/Unsuccessful (physical) delivery : other reasons
```

Or at least the latest status.

By the way, I was trying to use "Copy XPath" function from Developer Tools in Google Sheets and it never worked without additional modification. What is the reason?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look into Xpath Finder and Xpath Helper. They are extensions on Chrome which can help when writing Xpaths. Some Xpaths don't work. You have to write them yourself. It sounds like you may want to check out Vlookup on Google Sheets/Excel, too. Good luck!